# Import outlook contacts from a webpage with an Java Applet or ActiveX Control

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, outlook, applet

I want to import Outlook Contacts of a user when he accessed the webpage with a Java Applet or an ActiveX Control.

Is there any library to access the contacts or I can copy the .pst file on my server and then parse it and find the contacts ?

I found Java Outlook Connector http://www.moyosoft.com/joc/

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't expect the Applet's sandbox security model would let you access that kind of information. Perhaps ActiveX does, and in that case it should be reported as a security bug.

Normally, you should ask the user to export the contacts to some standard format and submit it through a web form. At least, that's what Facebook, GMail, LinkedIn and others do.